# Is it possible to run join serially using quatz in Xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am working in an application in which I need to schedule and run the job in serial manner. like I have 3 jobs.

When job1 finish then job2 start.
When job2 finish then job3 start.

If error occurred in any job then whole transaction will be rolled back.
Job2 depends on Job1 transaction and job3 depends on job1 and job2 transaction.

I know little bit about **JobListener** but wanted to configure the job in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Are job2 and job3 really *discrete jobs* which has to be scheduled separately too?

If so, you could run into ugly timing issues. It's very important to ensure that job2 and job3 couldn't run in multiple instances. Refactor your object in such a  way, you can use it as *job* and as object in another job.

If not, there isn't any reason to define job2 and job3 as scheduled jobs.
You just have to refactored your code.

Comment: thanks for replying we are not working in clustered environment so there is no chance these jobs will run multiple times, we need to be done in XML configuration only.